# session between multiple WCF services

Tags: wcf, session

I am new wcf and want some clarification, I have multiple WCF services (let suppose service01-service05 with per session mode) in a single project, now I want to know when I will create a client and calls the service01 then service02 and so on, will it be create the single session or session01, session02 (for each service seperate session) and so on.

If seperate session then what to do for a single session while calling multile services.

Answer (score 2):

There will be one session PER WCF service instance. WCF holds session state in memory, and manages it per service endpoint per proxy.

This also implies that if you kill and re-create a new proxy instance per call, you will lose the session state.

Comment: ok i got that, but if i want to maintain a single session for multiple services then what should i do? one thing more to achive functionality (enterpise level project)will it be better to create multiple services or just single service having multiple interfaces. my major concerns is now scaliblity.

Comment: You cannot maintain a single session for multiple services, because WCF manages session state per service endpoint, per proxy. Having multiple services means having multiple endpoints (at least 1 endpoint per service), and therefore multiple services cannot share session state.

What you could possibly do, is store state not in Session data but in a DB or in a caching mechanism, and then pass a Session ID in your service method calls. You would need a way to make sure session data gets cleaned up though.